# Docker: Internal UDP communication

Tags: udp, docker

Internal UDP communication seems broken in Docker (version 1.2.0)

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ docker run -t -i ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash

root@8dc91286015a:/# echo "hello" | nc -l -u 6000 &

root@8dc91286015a:/# echo "yo" | nc -u localhost 6000
```

I should see "hello", but I get no response. Same steps works outside of Docker, running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: is nc installed ? what shows `which nc`

Comment: `root@3e5085c2ae58:/# which nc` yields `/bin/nc`

Comment: Using `nc` with tcp is a success. This problem only occurs with UDP.

Comment: I see the same behaviour on the host (outside of Docker). I think this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strace` suggests it is attempting to connect to the ipv6 localhost address; specifying 127.0.0.1 or `nc -4` on the second command works for me.

For me, it works the same inside and outside of Docker.

Comment: The scenario outlined above works on my host machine, it does not work in Docker. Thus it is not independent of Docker. That being said, using `127.0.0.1` over `localhost` did solve my problem. It appears DNS resolve of `localhost` in Docker favors IPv6.